# Aframe: Binding Async data within Aframe using API response

Tags: ajax, aframe, webvr

I am trying to find out if we can integrate an API response within Aframe scene. For example, I want to get the information about an entity object when I move my cursor over it.
I know we can have maintained these static data with an a-text, but I am looking for AJAX based integration so that I can add/edit data from the backend.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom component, which will grab the text and use it as an `<a-text>` value. Execute the AJAX call inside an event listener (like a click, or any other one):

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {
    let self = this.el
    this.el.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          self.children[0].setAttribute("value", this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
      xhttp.send();
    })
  }
})
```

In a setup like this:

```
<a-entity foo>
  <a-text></a-text>
</a-entity>
```

Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yr7xkq1z/2/), exept with the ajax call, i took the ajax code from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xmlhttp).